# OpenStack and Docker

Tags: docker, openstack

When building private cloud using OpenStack, I would like it to support deploying and running Docker images, i.e. containers.

I find some announcements about [Cloud Native Computing Foundation](https://www.linuxfoundation.org/news-media/announcements/2015/07/new-cloud-native-computing-foundation-drive-alignment-among), and vendor specific positions e.g. [of Red Hat](https://www.redhat.com/en/about/blog/taking-stand-against-container-fragmentationwith-standards)

But as of September 2016, I can't find ready to use solution.

**How to make a private cloud supporting Docker?**

Comment: Start a VM running CoreOS...... Indeed any VM with docker installed.... Your question is very broad....

Answer (score 1):

- Install & launch docker containers inside an Openstack nova VM.
- Configuring Openstack setup compute driver as Docker driver itself. In this case, all the nova instances launched will be of docker container and the docker images can be stored in glance. Refer [openstack docker wiki](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Docker) for further details

Comment: Wiki says ‘It was introduced with the Havana release, but lives out-of-tree for Icehouse and Juno. Being out-of-tree has allowed the driver to reach maturity and feature-parity faster than would be possible should it have remained in-tree. It is expected the driver will return to mainline Nova in the Kilo release.’ So I saw that project as abandoned, it is already Mitaka (K->L->M)

Comment: Could you please extend, e.g. how to automatically get docker installed on Openstack Nova VM? Is second sentence other option or a next step?

Comment: To install Docker application automatically in a VM, provide the installation commands as part of user-data on booting an instance. Second point which I mentioned is an another approach of setting up openstack with docker.

Answer (score 1):

Consider also use nova-docker if you want to directly use docker instead of QEMU/KVM Hypervisors:

https://github.com/openstack/nova-docker